# How to extract a substring from string beginning to the second delimiter?

Tags: c++, string, substring

My string is: std::string achRecBuff = "usbaudio_1_req:some string";

From that string, I want to extract the string till the second delimiter '_'.
So the extracted string should be like "usbaudio_1".

How can I do that?

Comment: `<regex>` header from C++11 should suit you.

Comment: Show your work, what you have tried?

Comment: Are there anymore use-cases? Is the format of the strings always the same? Is the 2nd underscore always the last? Are there always 2 underscores?

Comment: No, as of now, I have only 2 underscores and the given solution solved my problem. But your question is right @Ralara . How we can do for multiple underscores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second underscore is always identical to the last underscore, a simple solution looks like this:

```
const auto pos = achRecBuff.find_last_of('_');

const std::string upTo2ndUnderscore = achRecBuff.substr(0, pos);
```

**Edit**: Considering a general case (thanks to @chris for pointing that out), this snippet also does what you want:

```
template <class Container, class Element>
Container beforeNthMatch(const Container& c, const Element& value, unsigned n)
{
    using std::cbegin;
    using std::cend;
    auto pos = cbegin(c);

    while (n-- != 0) {
        pos = std::find(++pos, cend(c), value);

        if (pos == cend(c))
            return {};
    }

    return {cbegin(c), pos};
}
```

In your case, the invocation looks like

```
const std::string upTo2ndUnderscore = beforeNthMatch(achRecBuff, '_', 2);
```

Cases like empty input containers are covered, and you can also use it with different cotainers, e.g. to find the nth given integer in a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Given that the OP said second and not last, I don't think this is what they're looking for.

Comment: But in this case, the second underscore is the last underscore.

Comment: This case is an example. It seems reasonable that "some string" could contain an underscore.

Comment: Yes, in my case, the second is the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) a couple of times like this:

```
std::string extract_special_part(std::string const& s)
{
    if(auto pos = s.find('_') + 1)
        if((pos = s.find('_', pos)) + 1)
            return s.substr(0, pos);

    return {};
}

int main()
{
    std::string achRecBuff = "usbaudio_1_req:some string";

    std::cout << extract_special_part(achRecBuff) << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
usbaudio_1
```

It relies on the *well defined behavior* of `std::string::npos` to *wrap round* to zero when you add one to it. If the character is not found then the `if()` statements fail because `std::string::npos + 1` becomes `0` which is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
        std::string a="usbaudio_1_req:some string" ;
        std::string::size_type f = a.find("_") ; // find 1st pos
        if ( f!=std::string::npos ) {
                f=a.find("_", f+1) ;    // find 2nd pos
                if ( f!=std::string::npos ) {
                        std::string b = a.substr(0, f) ;
                        std::cout << b << std::endl ;
                }
        }
        return 0 ;
}
```

the output is

```
usbaudio_1
```